# Запись в бд python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Не могу вставить массив в запрос

```
k = 789
kt = 'adn'
column_name= ['k','teh']// наименование столбцов
# print(teh2[0])
for tests in column_name:
    statement = "INSERT INTO KT("+ tests +") values (:1, :2)"
    cur.execute(statement, (k, kt))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Ошибка:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00913: too many values
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: statement = f"INSERT INTO KT({', '.join(column_name)}) values (:1, :2)" вместо цикла

Comment: @MaxU cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character выдает ошибку

Comment: @MaxU statement = "INSERT INTO KT("+ teh2[0] + "," + teh2[1] +") values ("+ val[0] + "," + val[1] +")" Если я выставлю хардкодом все записывает, но динамично не удается

Comment: Вы можете показать уже сгенерированный запрос?

Comment: @MaxU 
statement = "INSERT INTO KT("+ teh2[0] + "," + teh2[1] +") values (:1, :2)"
    print(statement)
INSERT INTO KT(k,teh) values (:1, :2),
cur.execute(statement, (k, kt))

Comment: что Выводит print(statement)? Вы показали как вы его создаёте, а я хотел увидеть что у вас при этом получилось

Comment: @MaxU statement = "INSERT INTO KT("+ teh2 +") values (:1, :2)" вот что выдал print(statement)

Comment: @MaxU да так и выдал

Comment: @MaxU то что вы попросили поставить вот результат 
    statement = f"INSERT INTO KT({', '.join(teh2)}) values (:1, :2)"
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Для того чтобы исправить ошибку нужно понять какой SQL запрос получает Oracle DB - пока вы не покажете сгенерированный запрос (не то как вы его собираете из переменных, а получившуюся SQL строку - “statement”) врядли вам смогут помочь

Comment: Пардон, забыл что у вас второй Python! Попробуйте так: statement = "INSERT INTO KT({}) values (:1, :2)”.format(', '.join(column_name))

Comment: @MaxU Чувак ты просто гений, спасибо тебе большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
statement = "INSERT INTO KT({}) values (:1, :2)".format(', '.join(column_name))
```